# Simple program throws FileNotFound Exception for relative path

Tags: java, netbeans, path

A dumb question, but after a lot of googling, I still can't get it to work.

```
    System.out.print("Start");

    File file = new File("TestFile.txt");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
```

When I run this, I get a FileNotFound exception.  I'm running on NetBeans, and I have placed the TestFile.txt inside the same package as the main class.  When I use the absolute path, it works.  I can see the see the file next to the .class file inside the build folder.  I've tried using the command line, and it doesn't work either.

Comment: *and I have placed the TestFile.txt inside the same package as the main class* - That's the issue. If you are accessing the file like this, you should put it in the `user.dir`. You can test it with `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative file paths are not relative to the location of the class file containing the code. They're relative to the directory from which the java executable is started.

Just like, when executing

```
ls foo
```

or

```
dir foo
```

ls/dir look for the foo directory in the current directory, and not in the directory where the ls executable or dir executable is located.

So, similarly, when executing

```
java com.foo.bar.MainClass
```

if the MaiClass file opens the file "foo.txt", it will look for it in the directory where you were when executing the command `java com.foo.bar.MainClass`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use relative paths the folder that has the file must be in the classpath, so you can put the file in the root folder (if you run the code from a jar file), or add the root folder to your classpath.

If you want to keep the file in that folder you have to include it into the classpath in order to get it work.

Also, the relative path for a java command line program is the root folder, so you can construct the relative path from that point too.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the text file in the 'working directory' of your application.  And if you don't want to do that, you should include the folder that contains this file in class path.